# How can I vectorize a code of monitoring each element of an array in MATLAB?

Tags: performance, matlab, vectorization, nested-loops

Suppose that I have a 1x2823 vector like:

```
a = [100 223 445 0 99 0 0 123 45 0 67 89 0 55 0 ........ 0 212];
```

Note that the vector is just an example.
I want a piece of code be executed just for that element of a that are bigger than `eps` and smaller than `DATA_NULL` (two constant values)
How can I vectorize this?
I know that I can have a loop and monitor each element of `a` seperately and then write the code in an `if` statement.
But this loop will be inside a much bigger loop and I don't want to use nested loops.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you want to do, but let's say you want to reassign these values:

```
a((a>eps)&(a<DATA_NULL))=NewValue;
```

You can also pass this subset as an argument to a function (providing it accepts vectors as argument). Let's say you want the absolute value of all the elements that match your criteria:

```
AbsOfConditionala=abs(a((a>eps)&(a<DATA_NULL)));
```

etc.